# How to create bootstrap subtheme using sass?

Tags: 7, theming

I am using latest bootstrap version(7.x-3.8) . I want create a subtheme by using SASS but i don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Create a New Sub-theme

1. Copy `bootstrap/starterkits/sass` folder into `sites/all/themes` or a respective `sites/*/themes` folder.
2. Rename the folder to a unique machine readable name. This will be your sub-theme's "name". For this example and future examples we'll use **subtheme**.
3. Rename `subtheme/sass.starterkit` to match the folder name and append .info (e.g. `subtheme/subtheme.info`).
4. Open `subtheme/subtheme.info` and change the name, description and any other properties to suite your needs.
5. Download and extract the latest 3.x.x version of [Bootstrap Framework Source Files](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) into the root of your new sub-theme. After it has been extracted, the directory should be renamed (if needed) so it reads `subtheme/bootstrap`.

## Compile Sass

1. Override default bootstrap variables in `subtheme/sass/_default-variables.scss`.
2. Edit `subtheme/sass/overrides.scss` as your fit to properly integrate with Drupal
3. Compile `subtheme/scss/style.scss` to `subtheme/css/styles.css`.

---

More Information : [Read Drupal-Bootstrap Documentation](http://drupal-bootstrap.org/api/bootstrap/docs%21subtheme%21README.md/group/subtheme/7)

Comment: As you say i create a sub theme. Now my confusion is that where i write my css . in style.scss or styles.css

Comment: `style.scss` is to glue all files for compile. `styles.css` is the output from `style.scss`. So if you want to change default bootstrap variables write in `_default-variables.scss` else write in `_overrides.scss`. Or you can import your own files in `style.scss` as you need.

Comment: @PolarBear Hi, I have one question, I did as described in your answer, but after this stage it is showing the site like without any css implementation like what we see when we install the base theme(like Zen). So, how can I apply the default bootstrap theming in my sub-theme so It provides the default bootstrap style and also provides the feasibility to alter it if we want to customize. Very thanks

Comment: @CodeNext Normally, after finished those steps will see the result like default bootstrap base-theme. Did you compile sass or clear cache? You can see the error of loading CSS by pressing `F12`.