# Creating a bootstrap sub-theme with the SASS starter kit

Tags: 7, theming

I am attempting to create a bootstrap sub-theme using the SASS starter kit in the the bootstrap base theme. I'm using bootstrap version 7-3.16.

I followed the directions here: [How to create bootstrap subtheme using sass?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/220314/how-to-create-bootstrap-subtheme-using-sass) as best as I could.

I copied the SASS starter kit into a new directory in the sites/all/themes directory and named it "bootsub". Then I changed the sass.starterkit file to "bootsub.info" and edited the file to reflect the name "bootsub".

Then I copied the bootstrap framework files into a file in the subtheme named "bootstrap". I had previously installed compass and sass.

I then ran the command "compass init" from the command line (in the subtheme root directory). This created the config.rb file. I then ran the command "compass compile" in the subtheme root directory.

I am still not able to see any styling on the site. I have flushed the cache and I have double checked to make sure that the subtheme is enabled and set as default and the bootstrap base theme is enabled.

I am including an images of the directory structure and a copy of the config.rb file

```
require 'compass/import-once/activate'
# Require any additional compass plugins here.

# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/sites/all/themes/bootsub"
css_dir = "stylesheets"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "javascripts"

# You can select your preferred output style here (can be overridden 
via the command line):
# output_style = :expanded or :nested or :compact or :compressed

# To enable relative paths to assets via compass helper functions. 
Uncomment:
# relative_assets = true

# To disable debugging comments that display the original location of 
your selectors. Uncomment:
# line_comments = false


# If you prefer the indented syntax, you might want to regenerate this
# project again passing --syntax sass, or you can uncomment this:
# preferred_syntax = :sass
# and then run:
# sass-convert -R --from scss --to sass sass scss && rm -rf sass && mv 
scss sass
```

[image: directory structure]

Answer (score -1):

Try using [Radix Theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/radix). Check how the compiler gulp is setup and try to replicate it to bootstrap sass.